# Is pnorm(q = (x - $\mu$)/$\sigma$) ever different from pnorm(q = x, mean = $\mu$, sd = $\sigma$)?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, normal-distribution

It is the case that the probability density for a standardized and unstandardized random variable will differ. E.g., in R

```
dnorm(x = 0, mean = 1, sd = 2)
dnorm(x = (0 - 1)/2)
```

However,
pnorm(q = 0, mean = 1, sd = 2)
pnorm(q = (0 - 1)/2)
yields the same value.

Are there any situations in which the Normal cumulative density function will yield a different probability for the same random variable when it is standardized versus unstandardized? If yes, is there a particular example in which this difference arises? If not, is there a general proof of this property?

Thanks so much for any help and/or insight!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a coding question, but I'll answer it anyway.

**Short answer:** yes, they may differ.

**Long answer:**

A normal distribution is usually thought of as y=f(x), that is, a curve over the domain of x.  When you standardize, you are converting from units of x to units of z.  For example, if x~N(15,5^2), then a value of 10 is 5 x-units less than the mean.  Notice that this is also 1 standard deviation less than the mean.  When you standardize, you convert x to z~N(0,1^2).  Now, that example value of 10, when standarized into z-units, becomes a value of -1 (i.e., it's still one standard deviation less than the mean).

As a result, the *area under the curve* to the left of x=10 is the same as the area under the curve to the left of z=-1.  In words, the cumulative probability up to those cut-offs is the same.

However, the *height* of curves is different.  Let the normal distribution curves be f(x) and g(z). Then f(10) != g(-1).  In code:

```
dnorm(10, 15, 5) != dnorm(-1, 0, 1)
```

The reason is that the act of standardizing either "spreads" or "squishes" the f(x) curve to make it "fit" over the new z domain as g(z).

Here are two links that let you visualize the spreading/squishing:

- https://academo.org/demos/gaussian-distribution/
- https://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/normal-distribution-graph-interactive.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is very illuminating. Say I know the variance of x is equal to 25 and I observe the value of 10. Then say I want to asses which values of the mean of x are most consistent with the observed value of 10 and known variance of 25. Is there a sense in which using dnorm(10, 15, 5) would yield the same evidential support for mean = 15 relative to mean \neq 15 as does using dnorm((10 – 15)/5)? I.e., does it matter if I use a likelihood based on the random variable x or a likelihood based on the random variable z?

Comment: "Most consistent with an observed value" is akin to asking about the likelihood.  The likelihood is a function of the parameter(s), conditional on the data and the model.  So in your example, it's a curve f(mu) over the domain of mu.  As you "move" around in mu-space, the likelihood will be higher or lower.  It does not matter which "scale" (x or z) you use.  With one data point (x=10), the likelihood will be at a maximum where mu_x=10.  Similarly, with one data point (z=-1), the likelihood will be at a maximum where mu_z=-1.